# Error using Mockito and Specs2

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

I have the following spec:

```
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

class LinkUserServiceSpec extends Specification with Mockito {

  val linkUserService = mock[LinkUserService]

  "The 'LinkUserService' isUserLinked method" should {
      "return false when a previously unlinked userId is passed in for a given service" in {
          linkUserService.isUserLinked("nobody", "YT") returns false

          linkUserService.isUserLinked("nobody", "YT") must beFalse
      }
  }
}
```

And the following dependency in my build.sbt:

`"org.specs2"              %%  "specs2"        % "2.2" % "test"`

However I get this error when I type `test` into the sbt console:

```
[error] bad symbolic reference. A signature in MocksCreation.class refers to type MockSettings
[error] in package org.mockito which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling MocksCreation.class.
[error] bad symbolic reference. A signature in MockitoStubs.class refers to term stubbing
[error] in package org.mockito which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling MockitoStubs.class.
[error] two errors found
[error] (test:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Sep 12, 2013 3:23:41 PM
```

Anyone know what this could be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently if you want to use Mockito with Specs2 you have to provide the dependency yourself, I added the following to my build.sbt and things started working:

`"org.mockito"          %   "mockito-all"   % "1.9.5"`

Comment: I confirm this. specs2 only has a few mandatory dependencies. All the other ones are optional, depending on the features you want to use.