# Error message when trying to run a Mockito test in Play

Tags: scala, playframework, mocking, mockito, specs2

I'm trying to run the following code in a test class in my play application to test Mockito:

```
trait DateWSClient {
  def currentDate: String
}

class DateProvider (dateWS: DateWSClient) {
  def currentYear = {
    dateWS.currentDate.split("/")(0)
  }
}

import org.specs2._
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito

class DateProviderSpec extends mutable.Specification with Mockito {

  "currentYear" should {
    "be the first part of the date returned by the WS" in {
      val clientMock = mock[DateWSClient]
      val formatter = new DateProvider(clientMock)
      clientMock.currentDate returns "2013/08/07"
      formatter.currentYear must beEqualTo("2013")
    }
  }
}
```

I got it from this article: http://workwithplay.com/blog/2013/08/07/mocking-with-mockito/

However when I run 'test' in the play terminal, I get the following error message:

```
[error] bad symbolic reference. A signature in MocksCreation.class refers to type MockSettings
[error] in package org.mockito which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling MocksCreation.class.
[error] bad symbolic reference. A signature in MockitoStubs.class refers to term stubbing
[error] in package org.mockito which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling MockitoStubs.class.
[error] two errors found
```

The same problem is described here: [Error using Mockito and Specs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773821/error-using-mockito-and-specs2), however this sollution doesn't change anything for me.

What does this error message mean exactly? And how do I solve this problem?

The version of play I use is: 2.1.2

Comment: can you print out your classpath with sbt? `show externalDependencyClasspath` and check that there is indeed `"org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5"` in the list.

Comment: It's not. If I add it, will it work? and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: See this link: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SBTDependencies on how to add dependencies to your Play project.

Comment: Added the line you gave earlier to the build file worked, thank you.

Comment: I added an answer so that you can close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5"` needs to be added to the list of dependencies.

See the [Play documentation on dependencies](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SBTDependencies) on how to do that.